# How do I tell which element a jquery click occurred on?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am handling a click on a list item with jquery:

```
$("#some_list li").click(function(event) {
    // magic happens here
    }
```

The list items look like:

```
<li><input type='checkbox'>Some text<span class='info'>(?)</span></li>
```

I want to have different behaviours depending on whether the user clicks within the (?), or anywhere else in the list. How can I detect which element the user clicked on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like `this`:

```
$(this)
```

All event handlers run in the context of the element, so `this` will refer to the native DOM object for the element that triggered the event.

However, this doesn't exactly answer your question – `this` will be the element that the handler was registered for.

To find the actual element that was clicked on (which can be a child of `this`), you should write `$(e.target)`

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a simple jquery code to get the count of clicked links.

```
var temp_str='';
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').click(function(e){e.preventDefault();});
    $(document).click(function(e){
        if($(e.target).data('count')==undefined)
        $(e.target).data('count',0);
            $(e.target).data('count',$(e.target).data('count')+1);

    $('a').each(function(i,item){if($(item).data('count')!=undefined)temp_str+=$(item).html()+" : "+$(item).data('count')+"<br>";});
    $('#helper').html(temp_str);
    temp_str='';
    });

    });
```